# Why does Python 3.5 Return a TypeError and not in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a working piece of code in Python 2.7:

```
def reversetomd5(knownhash):
  clean="" 
  for i in [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28]:
    clean+=knownhash[i]
 b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
 block=[]
 for i in xrange(2,24,3):
   p1 = b64.index(clean[i-2])
   p2 = b64.index(clean[i-1])
   p3 = b64.index(clean[i])
   block.append(p1 << 12 | p2 << 6 | p3)
 md5hash=""
 for i in block:
   n1 = i >> 8
   n2 = i & 0xff
   md5hash+=chr(n1)+chr(n2)
 return binascii.hexlify(md5hash)
```

I'm trying to get it working in Python 3.5  I swapped `xrange` with `range` but the character shifting at the bottom doesn't work anymore and returns `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.  I haven't been able to figure out what changed in Python 3 to cause that.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because Python 3 made a clearer distinction between bytestrings and Unicode text. Python 2 implicitly encodes and decodes, a source of many confusing bugs.

Comment: There are plenty of posts here on Stack Overflow alone that explain that exception, and there is the [Python porting HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) that covers text vs bytes too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working correctly.  `chr()` was replaced to return the `byte` equivalent of the character.  Had to change the `md5hash` initialization to an empty `byte` variable instead of a `string`.  Then just `.decode()` it at the end to return a nice string.

```
def reversetomd5(knownhash):
  clean="" 
  for i in [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28]:
    clean+=knownhash[i]
 b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
 block=[]
 for i in range(2,24,3):
   p1 = b64.index(clean[i-2])
   p2 = b64.index(clean[i-1])
   p3 = b64.index(clean[i])
   block.append(p1 << 12 | p2 << 6 | p3)
 md5hash=b''
 for i in block:
   n1 = i >> 8
   n2 = i & 0xff
   md5hash+=bytes[(n1)]+bytes[(n2)]
 return binascii.hexlify(md5hash).decode()
```